# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.10 on windows 8 machine/ error no5

Tags: installation, uefi, gpt

Installing crashes halfway through "Copying Files," showing an I/O device error error number 5.

There was problem in beginning of installation too--Ubuntu was not detecting the  installed Windows 8 system.

My system is a dell Inspiron 5520 laptop, with a 1 TB WDC hard disk in GPT, with EFI.

My current partition layout is:

102 MB EFI SYSTEM partition
200 GB Windows 8 ntfs
22 GB root Ext4
8 GB swap
20 GB home Ext4
680 GB ntfs Drive for storing all my files

I tried installing both from a DVD disc and a USB drive; both resulted in the same error.

The built-in Dell hardware diagnosis utility showed both hard disk and DVD drive as healthy.

What may be the reason and how can I install ubuntu along side my Windows 8 system?

Comment: Presumably you used the same ISO image to make the installation DVD and the installation USB, so if there's something wrong with that file, it could cause this problem. Did you [MD5 test](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the ISO image you downloaded? If so, please edit your question to include the result. If you didn't, please do so now, and then update your question with the result.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this article](http://www.intowindows.com/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu/)--this may help you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.